# Orientation change in Honeycomb

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, screen-orientation, android-configchanges

I have an activity that shouldn't be recreated after an orientation change. I added the following to the activity declaration in the manifest:

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

On Android 2.3 this works perfectly. On [HONEYCOMB_MR2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#HONEYCOMB_MR2) `onCreate` is called anyway when change the orientation.

Is there something else that needs to be done on HONEYCOMB_MR2 to prevent recreating the activity after an orientation change?

Comment: Have you tried `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"`? I wouldn't expect that to make a difference, but it's worth trying.

Comment: @CommonsWare It does not, but trying all the possible values I found one that works. See my answer.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Apparently using `orientation|screenSize` (?) prevents `onCreate` on Honeycomb and (so far) does not seem to break anything in previous Android versions.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

No idea why this is necessary and I don't really understand the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#configChanges) about this new value.

I suspect that in HONEYCOMB_MR2 upon an orientation change the activity considers this as two config changes: orientation and screen size. And both attempt to recreate the activity by default.

Comment: Yeah, those are new. What is your `android:targetSdkVersion` value?

Comment: android:targetSdkVersion="13"

Comment: OK, well, that would trigger what the docs say. This has to do with those new resource set qualifiers: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html Basically, since they expanded the former small/normal/large/xlarge and port/land stuff to include resource sets based on dimensions, they will consider changes in those dimensions to be configuration changes. Conceivably, there could be devices where those dimensions change not by orientation (e.g., dual-screen devices with second screen toggle-able on/off).

Comment: Makes sense. Regrettably, Android's flexibility is making it really complicated.

Comment: I never promised you a rose garden. Which is a good thing, since I don't own a rose garden, and it's tough to buy those in stores. :-)

Comment: Not having `screenSize` in my configChanges was causing `IllegalStateException`s stating that a fragment wasn't attached to an activity. I searched everywhere for what was causing this, since it was only happening on certain devices (3.2 and up, although I didn't realize that until I found this). Thanks!

Comment: @CommonsWare sir i hve a fragment that gets added and hidden and paused on certain clicks. but when i change the locale, the fragment disappears. it works on 4.2.2 and 4.0 but not 3.2. i have the fragment getting called but it simply doesnt appear , what could be wrong ? please assist.