# android:configChanges="orientation" does not work with fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, restart

I am just trying to adapt some of my applications for HoneyComb.

The issue iI am facing is the destruction of my activity on orientation change (landscape/portrait)

When I was using a classic activity, I wrote in the manifest:

But now, all these lines aren't working anymore!

Is there a workaround for that?

My code:

```
    <activity android:name=".TwitterActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />

    <activity android:name=".TwitterActivity$AppListFragment"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"  />
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Based on my experience with Honeycomb 3.0 and compatibility library (r1).

`configChange="orientation"` does work with fragments with respect to preventing the activity (to which it is applied) being re-created on an orientation change. If you want the `fragment` not to be re-created on activity re-creation then call `setRetainInstance` in `onCreate`.

Unless I'm missing something I don't quite get your second manifest entry, isn't `AppListFragment` a `Fragment`? If so then why is it listed as an entry in your manifest?

See [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968105/orientation-change-in-honeycomb) for new qualifiers which is likely to be causing this if you are targetting sdk 13, suggest trying `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`

Comment: The second manifest entry is just a test because I was so disappointed. I can promise you that setting configchange="orientation" does NOT work for the fragment inside the activity.

Comment: @Profete162 I'm not sure what you mean by 'does NOT work for the fragment inside the activity'. The fragment inside should have no impact on the recreation of the activity. What's your target sdk set to? See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968105/orientation-change-in-honeycomb) for possible answer.

Comment: Answer seem great, will go to work and give a try this evening, but I am pretty sure your answer will be accepted!

Comment: +1 for the `screenSize` hint and the link to the other SO answer.

Comment: From Google Doc (search "orientation" and read next two properties as well):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config

Answer (score 37):

I had a very similar problem but had to make a couple of additions to get it to work with various version (including ICS).

In the main app activity I added a slightly different version of what Jason offered.

```
<activity
android:name=".MyMainActivity"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" 
android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

I had this working on pre-Honeycomb with:

```
           <activity
        ....
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" 
        .... >
```

I had to make the first example to get it running on all versions.  I'm currently using fragments and ActionBarSherlock for backwards compatibility.

I also changed the way I was saving and reloading:

```
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Set up webview object
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.webview_layout, container, false);
        webview = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.webview_fragment);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Check to see if it has been saved and restore it if true
        if(savedInstanceState != null)
        {
            if (savedInstanceState.isEmpty())
                Log.i(tag, "Can't restore state because bundle is empty.");
            else
            {
                if (webview.restoreState(savedInstanceState) == null)
                    Log.i(tag, "Restoring state FAILED!");      
                else
                    Log.i(tag, "Restoring state succeeded.");      
            }

        }
        else 
        {
            // Load web page
            webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
            webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
            webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false); 
            webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);   
            webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true); 
            webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            webview.loadUrl(mTabURL);       
        }
        return v;
    }
```

The code for the save instance state method:

```
       @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        if(webview.saveState(outState) == null)
            Log.i(tag,"Saving state FAILED!");
        else
            Log.i(tag, "Saving state succeeded.");      
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped me with a similar problem I had while upgrading my app to ICS.

Answer (score 34):

Up to API 13 there was a new value to the configChanges attribute, `screenSize`

So if you're using large screens make sure to add screenSize in your configChanges attribute:

```
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

Comment: Will screenSize make a Crash on Api < 13?

Answer (score 5):

I was having this same problem (i.e., activity restarting) even without fragments.

I changed:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

to:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

That prevent the activity from restarting.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is quite late answer, but I recently faced this issue and was able to resolve this for Fragment Activity.

1) In Manifest,

```
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

2) In Class file, override the onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState). 
   Thats it! Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

In Manifest file, inside activity add this line

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Answer (score -1):

**Add this to Manifeast.Xml**

```
<android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
```

Its work for you.