# retain videoview in fragment when rotating

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

I have a activity who hold 2 fragments (one SlidingMenu and other a VideoPlayer with control and other views).

How Can I retain the video playing status when I'm rotating the device? the video is a HLS Stream, so, I don't need to start again the buffering when rotate.

I start playing with the savedInstanceState, but i can't get it work

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the same resources on on different screen orientations, you can [prevent fragment from recreating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139488/androidconfigchanges-orientation-does-not-work-with-fragments).

If you need to recreate fragment, you can store playback progress, and after recreation scroll video to stored position

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    ...
    if(playbackWasStarted) {
        video.pause();
        videoProgress = video.getCurrentPosition();
    }
    ...
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    ...
    if(playbackWasStarted && videoProgress!=0) {
        video.seekTo(videoProgress);
        video.start();
    }
    ...
}
```

**EDIT** Oh, I didn't noticed that this question is veeeery old...