# Android version 3.0 and orientation

Tags: android

when i set android target below 13 then the android configchanges attribute work fine means on create method not call, but if i set target version 13 and above then android config Changes attribute does not work and oncreate method recall on change of orientation.

Answer (score 0):

For target sdk 13 and above the recommended attribute is

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: thank you,but please tell me why android:configChanges="orientation|keybord" does not work for this unlike andorid version below 13.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139488/androidconfigchanges-orientation-does-not-work-with-fragments.

Comment: If the above solution suffice your need.. Its really appreciated to accept this as an answer !!!