# How to prevent activity from restart during orientation change?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have an activity which extends an AlertActivity. In that I am trying to play an audio file. When orientation changes audio goes stop. I want to continue playing audio even if the orientation changes. How can I prevent calling onPause and onStop when orientation changes? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to manifest and add this to your activity
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code : Add in Manifest File

```
<activity android:name=".Activity_name"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

Comment: Add it to the AndroidManifest.xml file

Answer (score 0):

you did not mention are you using fragments.
this code may help you

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

and also see this link

[orientation change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139488/androidconfigchanges-orientation-does-not-work-with-fragments)