# Android NullPointerException on Screen Orientation Change

Tags: android, android-orientation

I am narrowing down and explaining as simple as can,
main activity initiates an async task.

When orientation change `onCreate()` is recalled so `Async` is created once gain. so in `onPreExecute()` i lock my orientation and in `onPostExecute()` i release lock on orientation.  By this way if `Async` task has started another instance of task will never get created.

another issue has started, in main activity itself `findViewById()` returns null when i randomly keep changing the screen orientation. Re-producing once in 5-6 tries.

how to go on this? any help

Does `onCreate()` get re-called after completion of method or main thread... or is it instantaneous as soon as orientation get changed

Thank you

---------------updated

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ap_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="agilepoint.android.mobilebpm.main.LoginActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:logo="@drawable/menu_button"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden" 
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <data android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
 </application>
```

Comment: Any code would be useful to diagnose the problem

Comment: Post your manifest file and error trace.

Comment: You can also disable the app-restart on rotate in your manifest. Also, the long running task can be handled by service.

Comment: if you are rotating the app randomly what would you define as long running task .. 2 sec

Comment: i tried to set orientation in configChanges, onConfigurationChanged() is not getting called, onCreate is called as always

Comment: Please post your `onCreate()`.

Comment: Mark, i found solution. posted just few minutes back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found my solution...

[android:configChanges="orientation" does not work with fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139488/androidconfigchanges-orientation-does-not-work-with-fragments)

if you want to prevent runtime restarts due to orientation change when developing for API level 13 or higher (as declared by the `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` attributes), you must include the `screenSize` value in addition to the `orientation` value. That is, you must declare `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`.

Answer (score 0):

Add android:configChanges="orientation" for that perticular activity in manifest.

Comment: i have tried to set orientation in configChanges, onConfigurationChanged() is not getting called, onCreate is called as always.