# ActivityManager killing application multiple times

Tags: android, android-activity, rotation, screen-rotation

I'm having some issues with my application and it's activity. There's been a couple of reports on my application that sometimes after turning the screen of and turning it back on the activity would have reset for no apparent reason.

I had issues reproducing it, but managed eventually. It turns out that if you turn off the screen of at the same time as you're rotating the device now and then Android kills my activity and recreates it multiple times in close succession. This without calling onSaveInstanceState so my state isn't preserved.

Here's the complete logcat which is cropped around the relevant time http://pastebin.com/SXTLz0Q4. I'm logging with my tag "Wendlerized" and I'm printing whenever onDestroy, onSaveInstanceState and onCreate is called.

I'd love some help reading the log as I can't find anything that I can connect with my application and why it's being killed.

Br Johan

Comment: this link might help you

  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139488/androidconfigchanges-orientation-does-not-work-with-fragments

Comment: Adding configChanges isn't an option