# Android settings change when scrolling

Tags: android, preferencefragment, switchpreference

I have a pretty standard PreferenceFragment, it is implemented using a FragmentActivity.  Nothing really special but I have some (small number) of people using that app reporting that as they scroll the settings some randomly turn themselves off or on.  The definitions are pretty simple: 1 below

```
    <SwitchPreference
        android:key="speechEnabled"
        android:persistent="true"
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:title="some title"
        android:summary="summary text" />
```

This is a video from one person reporting the issue:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx67XBdVKhrKUDVJS24zWmtUa1k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please post your PreferenceFragment code.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell anything without seeing the code, but I've come across the issue with an Activity being re-created on portrait/landscape change.
In order to fix it, I added `android:configChanges="orientation"` in the manifest for the Activity, like this:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.app.ExampleActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:configChanges="orientation" >
</activity>
```

You might also need to call `setRetainInstance`, for more info see this post:
[android:configChanges="orientation" does not work with fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139488/androidconfigchanges-orientation-does-not-work-with-fragments/7139554#7139554)