# Application works fine in portrait mode but crashes in landscape mode

Tags: android, debugging, android-manifest, landscape-portrait

i've made an application and the last thing i did was add landscape variation to different activities, everything works fine in portrait mode and landscape for my activities except for my home acitivty, whenever i rotate my screen the app crashes, i dont see any actual error in the logcat this is all i see:

```
.samsung.android.fmm-7t6JLtIv78w9SFws4HkTWw==" dev="mmcblk0p78" ino=684539 scontext=u:r:system_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:apk_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 SEPF_SM-A115F_10_1021 audit_filtered
2021-06-09 04:33:18.691 647-647/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1623205998.683:869247): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=28307 comm="oid.sm.provider" name="com.samsung.android.lool-CWSBTk5GB0zn5KPm1k3Rpg==" dev="mmcblk0p78" ino=22145 scontext=u:r:system_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:apk_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 SEPF_SM-A115F_10_1021 audit_filtered
2021-06-09 04:33:19.581 28251-28284/? E/BatteryFasDaoImpl: traverseFasDatabase : 10187 com.google.android.videosis disabled now, so we skip !!
2021-06-09 04:33:23.012 647-647/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1623206003.003:869248): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=28475 comm="oid.sm.provider" name="com.samsung.android.lool-CWSBTk5GB0zn5KPm1k3Rpg==" dev="mmcblk0p78" ino=22145 scontext=u:r:system_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:apk_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 SEPF_SM-A115F_10_1021 audit_filtered
```

i've tried to solve this issue by checking answers of this quesiton:
[My app is crashing in landscape mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34369579/my-app-is-crashing-in-landscape-mode)
but it didnt work out for me, it still crashes, i have two different styles for portrait and landscape, this is my portrait design:
[image]
and this is how it should look like in landscape
[image]
the error didnt happen when i added

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
```

to manifest inside the home activity but the problem is it didnt show up the landscape design i made, instead it just rotated the portrait one directly, i removed the attribute screensize and the app crashed again, I have no clue how to solve this, please help me. and thank you.

Comment: Without any code, it's fairly impossible to help. When you encounter a crash, it's best to check both the `Run` and `Logcat` windows of the IDE. Please ensure the `Run` window is open before launching the application and try reproducing the crash again. Afterward, we can help.

Comment: @buggily hello, thank you ive already solved it, i debugged and found the error

Answer (score 1):

in case this error happens to anyone in the future, my problem was that I've declared a button in portrait mode and forgot to add it in landscape mode , a button which I've used in another activity so it kept returning null object reference