# Android WebView refresh on orientation change

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an app that uses webview to load a URL. It has a login function. After logging in, it will redirect to a main page. My codes are as below.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
    } else {
        loadURL();
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                loadURL();
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}

private void loadURL() {
    //myWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.0.198:8080/dashboard/");

    myWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.0.156:8080/dashboard/");
}
```

And below is my AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.tg_david.myapplication">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

As you can see, I have included `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`, but it still doesn't work. The WebView still refreshes every time the phone changes the orientation. When it refreshes, the page will be redirected back to login page. Could it be because the WebView clear the session when the phone orientation changes and forced the page to logout?

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is Override onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState ){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mWebView.saveState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

and one other solution could be to update your Activity tag in manifest to

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
```

[1.Your question is already answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36987144/preventing-webview-reload-on-rotate-android-studio)

[2.Here is one tutorial](https://twigstechtips.blogspot.in/2013/08/android-retain-instance-of-webview.html)

Comment: nope, still doesn't work. I added the 2 Overrides and changed my manifest too. it always refreshed and forced me to re-login.

Answer (score 1):

In latest Android versions , it is simply sufficient to mention in the manifest `android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"`

Add or remove the above parameters as required .
In many cases,  we have a Splash activity too , where we generally miss these options , I could fix my case by mentioning the same parameters above and overriding the function

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

in Splash activity.

Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works well for me:

(1) In AndroidManifest.xml add this line
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"

Like this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

(2) Then in MainActivity.java verify savedInstanceState

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mainContext = getApplicationContext();
    ----
    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    prepareWebView();
    myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(myJavaScriptInterface, "WEB2Android");

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        myWebView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.appbiz.ro/foto_konta");
            }
        });
    }
    ----
}
```

(3) and then:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState )
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    myWebView.saveState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    myWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
}
```