# When I rotate my screen, the javascript stop working untill I reopen my WebView app even if i reload it do not work

Tags: java, android-studio

I am new and only doing this app for my website. in my website I have map and some small java. 
untill I rotatr mobile sreen it work fine but if I rotate it unable to see map an fuction that made by javascript but if I reopen my app it work again. please help if anyone can.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    } else {
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        checkConnection();
    }
}
```

and at the end i hve write this to prevent reload from beganing.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    webView.saveState(outState);
}
```

Comment: You should try to improve the question since i'm having trouble to understand, what you want to asking. Also i think this is not enough information to help you

Comment: I have try to post full code of my app but stack overflow do not accept.. My app is a android studio webview base... I have a website with google map. I code it simple way to view my website and its functionality which some javascripts it work fine but when I rotate screen javascript stop working.

Comment: I would suggest to test if it's related to the javascript inside the webview...
So try to make a simple example which just shows a button and rotate the phone. when you rotate and it works, then it is somehing in your code and not a bug in the webView... 1st step

Comment: I have button with javascript .when you rotate and it not works...

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36987144/preventing-webview-reload-on-rotate-android-studio

Comment: I have done this before and not reload my web page from start but my problem is javascript stop working.