# How to prevent a WebView to get recreated on orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview, android-lifecycle

I have a really heavy loading `WebView` in a `Fragment`.

The `WebView` takes about 2-4 seconds to load the url.

Every time the orientation is changed the WebView reloads the Url and it is a really bad user experience.

Is there a way to leave the url/WevView alive when the orientation changes?

Thanks

---

I forgot to add i cant add orientation to the manifest because of how the app is built.

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
```

So answers i found don't help me in my case.

Comment: This is one of those cases where [`android:configChanges` in the manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#config) may be appropriate, to avoid the destroy/recreate cycle for common configuration changes. Make sure that you are still using a `ViewModel` or something to deal with those configuration changes that you do not address via `android:configChanges`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Preventing WebView reload on Rotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131025/android-preventing-webview-reload-on-rotate)

Comment: @Philio see my edit