# onSurfaceCreated() called every time orientation changes

Tags: android, opengl-es, orientation

I'm implementing the GLSurfaceView.Renderer like so:

```
public class GL20Renderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    private static GL20Renderer mInstance = new GL20Renderer();
    private GL20Renderer() {}
    public static GL20Renderer getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        Log.e("App", "onDrawFrame()");
    }
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        Log.e("App", "onSurfaceChanged()");
    }
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        Log.e("App", "onSurfaceCreated()");
    }

}
```

This class is implemented in the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private GLSurfaceView mGLView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        // Create a GLSurfaceView instance and set it as the ContentView for this Activity
        mGLView = new GL20SurfaceView(this);
        setContentView(mGLView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mGLView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mGLView.onResume();
    }

}
```

GL20SurfaceView is:

```
public class GL20SurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
    public GL20SurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        // Create an OpenGL ES 2.0 context.
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

        // Set the Renderer for drawing on the GLSurfaceView
        setRenderer(GL20Renderer.getInstance());
    }
}
```

Very simple as you can see.
When I now start the App, the onSurfaceCreated() method is correctly called, follow by one call of onSurfaceChanged().

Problem now is: Whenever the device orientation changes, **I get another call of onSurfaceCreated() followed by onSurfaceChanged()**.

In my understanding, the onSurfaceCreated() method is called whenever a new surface needs to be created. My question is: Why does it do that whenever I change just the device orientation? Shouldn't it be sufficient that only a onSurfaceChanged() call is triggered in order to adjust the viewport?

Note that I don't put my device to sleep when changing the orientation.

Comment: When orientation changes activity is recreated by default. If you want stop reloading activity you need to specify "configChanges" attribute in manifest.xml file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DO this way

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            />
```

Comment: More infos on `configChanges="orientation"` [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968105)

Answer (score 1):

The one of advantages of OpenGL that you draw regards to screen size. It gives you ability to handle all Android resolutions.

I'm not sure how it works with `GL20` (sure the same like GL10).

As I know in `onSurfaceChanged` provides several configurations for OpenGL based on length/width of your screen.

For example `glViewport`

It is necessary to call `glViewport` handler when `GL` view dimensions are modified.

Only if you have width = height is unnecessary but its other story.

*as exampe*

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {

    // prevent 0 divide
    if(height == 0) {
        height=1;
    }

    screenWidth = width;
    screenHeight = height;
    ratio = (float) width/height;
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glOrthof(0, width, 0, height, -10f, 10f);
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
```

If you want to avoid that, add to Manifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name="Activity"
  android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation">
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. When I add the `glViewport` in the `onSurfaceChanged` section, I get the same problem.

What does the manifest.xml modification do?

Comment: take a look on example I posted, last row.... If you want to disable screen change on rotation add to your Activity `android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation`

Comment: The changes to the Manifest.xml were enough to make the magic happen: It works now! What would be the correct interpretation of why this works? Does the config change tell the application that I want to listen to orientation changes, which otherwise wouldn't be correctly handled?

Comment: after your Manifest change you do not get `onSurfaceChanged` call, right?  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: You probably mean `onSurfaceCreated`? Your changes to the Manifest were the ones who made me solve the problem. Now I only get a `onSurfaceChanged` when chaning the orientation (which is the expected behaviour).
I will accept your answer, as it correctly solves my problem.
To dig deeper: As far as I understand, Android picks a config that matches to the device. And everytime this config changes, a call to `onSurfaceCreated` will be triggered.
Note that orientation change was working before I added the Manifest change. It was just triggering an unnecessary call to `onSurfaceCreated`