# Android OpenGL: GLSurfaceView.Renderer.onDrawFrame() called twice at startup

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

I have a simple Android application which uses OpenGL (via *GLSurfaceView*).
Code is below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new MyGLSurfaceView(this));
    }

    class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
        MyGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            setEGLContextClientVersion(2);        // OpenGL ES 2.0
            setRenderer(this);                    // callbacks go to this class
            setRenderMode(RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY); // draw on request
        }

        public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) { }

        public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) { }

        public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
            /* if (startup) do_only_once(); */
            try { Thread.sleep(250); } catch (Exception ignored) { }
        }
    }
}
```

At the application startup *onDrawFrame()* (of *GLSurfaceView.Renderer*) **called twice most of times**.
As far as I know, *onSurfaceChanged()* (of *GLSurfaceView.Renderer*) should call *onDrawFrame()*, but I don't understand why it happens several times.

I would like to compute and draw some "background" objects, that should be done only once. I use *setRenderMode(RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY)*. But *onDrawFrame()* is still called several times. **How can I make it to be called only once? What is the reason of such repetitive calling?**

Adding Logging for these functions (and also some default *Activity* callbacks) in the start and the end of each will result in output below. Activity lifecycle seems to work fine:

```
// Example of function with Logging:
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("__DEBUG__", "onCreate() {");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new MyGLSurfaceView(this));
    Log.d("__DEBUG__", "onCreate() }");
}

22:12:46.361 __DEBUG__: onCreate() {
22:12:46.376 __DEBUG__: MyGLSurfaceView() {
22:12:46.376 __DEBUG__: MyGLSurfaceView() }
22:12:46.430 __DEBUG__: onCreate() }
22:12:46.431 __DEBUG__: onStart() {
22:12:46.431 __DEBUG__: onStart() }
22:12:46.432 __DEBUG__: onResume() {
22:12:46.433 __DEBUG__: onResume() }
22:12:46.498 __DEBUG__: onSurfaceCreated() {
22:12:46.498 __DEBUG__: onSurfaceCreated() }
22:12:46.498 __DEBUG__: onSurfaceChanged() {
22:12:46.498 __DEBUG__: onSurfaceChanged() }
22:12:46.498 __DEBUG__: onDrawFrame() {
22:12:46.748 __DEBUG__: onDrawFrame() }
22:12:46.754 __DEBUG__: onDrawFrame() {
22:12:47.004 __DEBUG__: onDrawFrame() }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it normal for the "activity.onCreate()" method to be called multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588682/is-it-normal-for-the-activity-oncreate-method-to-be-called-multiple-times)

Comment: @muradm, my _Activity.onCreate()_ works fine (called only once, according to Log), the question is about _GLSurfaceView_ lifecycle.

Comment: According to log everything is called twice. And your `GLSurfaceView` is initialized within `onCreate()` method. So if it is called twice, then `onCreate()` is called twice. Otherwise you are initializing `GLSurfaceView` also somewhere else, which is not illustrated in code snippets.

Comment: @muradm, for logging I used "func_name() **{**" at the beginning ot _func_name()_ and "func_name() **}**" at the end of it. It shows that new _onDrawFrame()_ is called only after the end of previous one.

Comment: @muradm, added an example of Logging. Each function should be printed 2 times

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30034277/onsurfacechanged-called-twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've studied platform code for *GLSurfaceView* and found that *onDrawFrame()* could be triggered twice, once of them in ctor.

I created an AOSP merge request with a proposed fix which could be found here: https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/base/+/858050.
However, it was "rejected" as being not too much important considering possible risks...

The only way to handle this is to implement simple state machine with switch-case inside *onDrawFrame()*. Need to keep "initial" state and redraw initial elements (backgroud in my case) untill real draw request comes (first requests switches state machine to "normal" state).